# WCF giving cross-domain error on a service deployed on the same server as an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I deployed an asp.net web application that contains a WCF service. I updated the ServicesReferences.ClientConfig file to point to the live address of the .svc file representing the service.

However, when I try to consume the service in the live deployed website I get a cross domain error.

I'm wondering why that is the issue.

Comment: i am getting an [Arg_SecurityException]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link.I hope it will help you to solve cross domain error.

[allow cross-domain access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)